# User login page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my user log in page I have two text boxes, one is for inserting the username and the another one is for inserting the password, and i have one button to submit.

If the username and password are correct then it redirect to the next page, that is welcome page. And now my question is:

If I type the welcome page url directly on the browser then that page is loaded without checking the username and password, but I want to stop this action, how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC or plain ASP.NET?

Comment: what is plain asp.net? Do you mean webforms?

Comment: plain ASP.NET is webforms, yes.

Comment: its just a normal asp.net page

Answer (score 5):

The best is that after entering username and password u should compare it from database values if both matches then move on to the login page otherwise show an invalid username or pass error

Answer (score 2):

Here is documentation of how to implement [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: This is the only answer that directly addresses the question and uses standard ASP.NET tools to implement.

Answer (score 1):

On the Page Load event of the Welcome Page. Check the Following condition to make sure whether the Request is Authenticated or Not.

```
if(!IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

For the Complete Reference about setting an authentication options refer to this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide some content from non-authorized users you may use `[Authorize]` atrribute on full controller or some actions. That'l redirect user to default page specified in web.config file `<authentication>` section

Answer (score 0):

The most common authentication is to have a table in your database where you store the credentials.On clicking login button validate the credentials against your database if it exists add a session variable which stores something like username or userid.In your master page check whether the session is null if it is re direct  them to the login page